# Хочу выбрать направление

Tags: python

Во многих ВУЗах присутствуют направления называемые прикладная информатика. Хочу спросить, что это такое?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Когда я заканчивал ВУЗ это называлось у нас "прикладная математика". По итогу практически ничего из ВУЗ-овской программы мне не пригодилось, всё, что мне нужно было для работы программистом, я выучил сугубо самостоятельно. )

Answer (score 1):

http://obrazovanie66.ru/spec/prikladnaya-informatika/

Но это в теории. А на практике -  открываете сайт конкретного вуза по той кафедре, где эта информация заявлена и читаете, что там написано, какой конкретно учебный план они предлагают, и где работают их выпускники. Или вы хотите, что-бы за вас кто-то такую аналитику сделал и вам ее тут представил в кратком изложении?